# attr('id','new id') not working to update the id of multiple div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

**I have Multiple Div which contain the delete button.

Once I click the button I need to update the Id of every div below the deleted Div.**

```
<div id="btn1" name="btn1"> Delete Button</div>
<div id="btn2" name="btn2"> Delete Button</div>
<div id="btn3" name="btn3"> Delete Button</div>
<div id="btn4" name="btn4"> Delete Button</div>
```

If I delete the `btn2` then `btn3` id should change to `btn2` and `btn4` id should change to `btn3`.
I have tried with `att()` function but its not working.

```
<div id="btn1" name="btn1"> Delete Button</div>
<div id="btn2" name="btn2"> Delete Button</div>
<div id="btn3" name="btn3"> Delete Button</div>


$('#btn' + i + '').attr('id', 'btn' + i - 1 + '')
```

Comment: Where's your code that you have tested but is not working?

Comment: I have mentioned in the question. i need to uodate the id of <Div id='btn1'name='btn1'></Div>

Comment: I mean where is your Javascript or jQuery code?

Comment: added the part of code

Comment: ids should be unique. i would avoid changing them.

Comment: I have tried to change the name  but that also doesn't working with attr

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
$("[id^=btn]").click(function(){
  var prevId = this.id;
  $(this).nextAll("[id^=btn]").each(function(){
     var tmpId = this.id;
     this.id = prevId;
     prevId = tmpId;
  });
  $(this).remove();
  $("[id^=btn]").each(function(){
     console.log("Name:", $(this).attr("name"), "ID:", this.id)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn1" name="btn1"> Delete Button</div>
<div id="btn2" name="btn2"> Delete Button</div>
<div id="btn3" name="btn3"> Delete Button</div>
<div id="btn4" name="btn4"> Delete Button</div>
```

I don't really know what you're using this for but I'm sure that there are better ways of doing it.

The important part in the code above is `nextAll`, you can find out more about it [HERE](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Comment: If i use the same logic on text box .Will it retain the data after changing the ID?

Comment: @piyush Yes, the data should remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

The last part of your code, i.e. `'btn' + i - 1 + ''`, returns `NaN`. You need to put `i - 1` into parentheses: `(i - 1)`. Plus the `+ ''` parts are unnecessary.

So you can try: `$('#btn' + i).attr('id', 'btn' + (i - 1))`

The answer by Titus is more comprehensive so you should probably use it – or do something completely different altogether as others have also suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Number of ways to do this. Here is another that might work for you. This is more fluid.

```js
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
  var btns = [];
  var $that = $(this);
  $that.parent().find(".btn").each(function(ind, elem) {
    if ($(elem).attr("id") != $that.attr("id")) {
      btns.push($(elem));
    }
  });
  var res = confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this?");
  if(res){
    console.log("Removing " + $that.attr("id"));
    $that.remove();
    $.each(btns, function(key, $item) {
      console.log("Re-labeling " + $item.attr("id"));
      $item.attr({
        id: "btn-" + (key + 1),
        name: "btn-" + (key + 1)
      });
      console.log("New Label " + $item.attr("id"));
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="btn-1" name="btn-1" class="btn"> Delete Button</div>
  <div id="btn-2" name="btn-2" class="btn"> Delete Button</div>
  <div id="btn-3" name="btn-3" class="btn"> Delete Button</div>
  <div id="btn-4" name="btn-4" class="btn"> Delete Button</div>
</div>
```

You may also want to add a `confirm()` condition within the `click` event. I added it to my example.

You do not have to use an array. For me, it's an extra control layer. This give you an easy way to group and manage the jQuery Objects you want to manipulate. Using `$.each()` to then iterate over that array, you can easily re-assign the `id` and `name` based on the array index.

Using an `id` with `"-"` can also be helpful for other attribute selectors, like `[name|="value"]`:

> **Description:** Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value either equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a hyphen (-).

See more: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/